# Reading RGB values of a pixel with LibTiff - C#

Tags: c#, libtiff, geotiff, libtiff.net, rgbcolor

I want to read RGB values of a pixel in C#, I tried using following code found [here](https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/html/98c3da41-bb2c-4bba-9a94-5ba32069aab5.htm).

```
             int[] raster = new int[height*width];
             var b =  tiffreader.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster);

             for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
                {
                    int offset = (height - j - 1) * width + i;
                    color.R = Tiff.GetR(raster[offset]);
                    color.G = Tiff.GetG(raster[offset]);
                    color.B = Tiff.GetB(raster[offset]);
             }
```

But I dint get What is this offset and why raster is in 1D when the Image is 2D. can some one help me in understanding the offset and raster thing in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 2D byte array (and in this case, bitmap) is basically still a "normal" 1D array that  allows access by two separate indices for convenience.

Example:

```
  0123456789
0 ##########
1 **********
2 XXXXXXXXXX
3 YYYYYYYYYY
```

`#,*,X,Y` denote the bytes in each entry

is actually (in memory)

```
##########**********XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYY
```

So that formula to map the indices is

```
int offset = i * width + j
```

with `i` being the row and `j` the column index.

---

In case of this TIFF image this is a little different because it is assumed that the origin is at the lower-left corner:

```
  0123456789
3 ####OO####
2 ##OO##OO##
1 ##OOOOOO##
0 ##OO##OO##
```

Thus,

```
int offset = (height - j - 1) * width + i;
```

is the formula that maps the two 2D indices to the 1D index of the raster array.

Comment: But the offset value when i=0;j=0 is height*width. does this mean thats the index for RGB values of 1st # in first row ? I though for the first # the index should be 0, and first * is 10, X  is 20 .... Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: sorry, the tiff image is a little different than my example. edited my answer @Manikanta